# Hibernate annotation-based bean definition with xml-configured bean validation

Tags: hibernate, validation, configuration

Can I configure hibernate bean validation in xml file if entities declared by annotations in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can have one not both, go with hibernate annotations because annotations are a better choice for a new application, since it makes the application free from XML files. It is also less code and maintenance is easy. It also helps for refactoring the application (with IDE like Eclipse/NetBeans, etc.), which is the problem with XML since you need to change it manually.

Comment: I can't use validation annotations by some reason.
You are not right, I just tested this. My bean persistence was declared by @Entity annotation, validation was in validation.xml in classpath and it work normal.  
**So answer is - Yes, it can be done**